# Scapy: Attribute Error: 'Tuple' Object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: scapy

```
pkt = srp(Dot11(type=0,subtype=4,addr1 = 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx', addr2 = 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'), iface = 'wlan0')
```

If I type:

pkt.summary()
pkt.show()
pkt.sprintf()
pkt.decode_payload_as() 
pkt.pdfdump()
pkt.command()

I get the **Attribute error:  'tuple' object has no attribute 'e.g. summary'**

This works if it's an IP or eth0 packet but not if its a WLAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code. Unlike `sniff()`, `srp()` (like `sr()`) returns a Tuple of two elements:

- a `SndRcvList` instance, for packets for which Scapy has received an asnwer.
- a `PacketList` instance, for sent packets for which Scapy has not received an answer.

You could write:

```
>>> ans, unans = srp([your packet here], iface='wlan0')
>>> ans.summary()
[...]
>>> unans.summary()
[...]
```